# Incrementing 'i' in scala for loop by differing amounts depending on circumstance

Tags: scala, for-loop, increment

I want to write a for loop in scala, but the counter should get incremented by more than one (the amount is variable) in some special cases.

Comment: `val start, end, step = ???; for { i <- start to end by step}`

Comment: Why don't you show a little work first, let us know what you've tried before asking for help.  We're not here to do your work for you.

Comment: @senia That does not do what has been asked, here.  Your loop will always increment by the same amount, not a variable one.

Comment: Do you need eagerly for comprehension or you fine with just looping in some way? I'm asking because it is good use case for recursion.

Comment: Atul, you probably need to say at least a little more about the detail of what you want, or this will end up closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a combination of a filter and an external var.  Here is an example:

```
var nextValidVal = 0
for (i <- 0 to 99; if i >= nextValidVal) {
  var amountToSkip = 0
  // Whatever this loop is for
  nextValidVal = if (amountToSkip > 0) i + amountToSkip + 1 else nextValidVal
}
```

So in the main body of your loop, you can set `amountToSkip` to *n* according to your conditions.  The next *n* values of i´s sequence will be skipped.

If your sequence is pulled from some other kind of sequence, you could do it like this

```
var skip = 0
for (o <- someCollection if { val res = skip == 0; skip = if (!res) skip - 1 else 0; res } ) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

If you set `skip` to a positive value in the body of the loop, the next *n* elements of the sequence will be skipped.

Of course, this is terribly imperative and side-effecty.  I would look for other ways to to this where ever possible, by mapping or filtering or folding the original sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your own stream to reflect step, for example:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream
import ForStream._
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val range = 0 to 20 by 1 withVariableStep; // in case you like definition through range
    //val range = ForStream(0,20,1) // direct definition
    for (i<- range) {
      println(s"i=$i")
      range.step = range.step + 1
    }
  }
}

object ForStream{
  implicit def toForStream(range: Range): ForStream = new ForStreamMaster(range.start, range.end,range.step)
  def apply(head:Int, end:Int, step:Int) = new ForStreamMaster(head, end,step)
}

abstract class ForStream(override val head: Int, val end: Int, var step: Int) extends Stream[Int] {
  override val tailDefined = false
  override val isEmpty = head > end
  def withVariableStep = this
}

class ForStreamMaster(_head: Int, _end: Int, _Step: Int) extends ForStream(_head, _end,_Step){
  override def tail = if (isEmpty) Stream.Empty else new ForStreamSlave(head + step, end, step, this)
}

class ForStreamSlave(_head: Int, _end: Int, _step: Int, val master: ForStream) extends ForStream(_head, _end,_step){
  override def tail = if (isEmpty) Stream.Empty else new ForStreamSlave(head + master.step, end, master.step, master)
}
```

This prints:

i=0

i=2

i=5

i=9

i=14

i=20

You can define ForStream from Range with implicits, or define it directly. But be carefull:

1. You are not iterating Range anymore!
2. Stream should be immutable, but step is mutable!

Also as @om-nom-nom noted, this might be better implemented with recursion

Comment: This assumes the variance in the step is independent of the state in the for loop.  How would you implement it to be controllable from within the loop (which I *think* is what the OP is asking for).

Comment: Sorry I did not get what you mean. It is controllable within loop through `stream.step = stream.step + 1`. Maybe OP should provide more info when step should be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the do-while loop?

```
var x = 0;
do{
...something
if(condition){change x to something else}
else{something else}
x+=1
}while(some condition for x)
```