# How can I achieve multiple step in scala range

Tags: scala

How can I achieve multiple step in scala range

Like this:
var r = 1 to 100 by (2, 3, 4)

And the last number 4, if there are more to step, will be the repeat step.

or bonus: something like with mode
1. var = 1 to 100 by (2, 3, 4) review // review steps from 2, 3, 4 again.
2. var = 1 to 100 by (2, 3, 4) last // use last number as final steps.
3. var = 1 to 100 by (2, 3, 4) random // use steps randomly within these numbers.
4. var = 1 to 100 by (2, 3, 4) reverse // use steps in reverse and reverse manner.

Comment: You'd have to write some code to do that... Have you tried it? Don't be afraid to show us.

Comment: no not yet. I need help. but there's some kind of hint. [on this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738623/incrementing-i-in-scala-for-loop-by-differing-amounts-depending-on-circumstanc) by @Piro

Comment: Check scan method which I think would help

Comment: @mijzcx what kind of help do you need?

Comment: @Dima If you have an implementation on how could this be done. I consider that helpful.  

say `var r = 1 to 20 by (2, 3, 4 ) last`
result: Range( 1, 3, 6, 10, 14, 18 )

Something like this raw:
    scala> `var r = 1 to 20 by 2`
    r: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19)

    scala> `var r = 3 to 20 by 3`
    r: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18)

    scala> `var r = 6 to 20 by 4`
    r: scala.collection.immutable.Range = Range(6, 10, 14, 18)

Comment: @mijzcx I can probably come up with an implementation in, say, a couple of hours. My rate is $350/hour, so, the bill to you would come out in the neighborhood of $700. How does that sound? SO is not a  "do my homework for free website". You may want to try freelancer.com, you could, probably get it done for a lot cheaper there.

Comment: Mijzcx, as @Dima says, you need to write some code. Just re-stating your desired output isn't doing that.  Please show what you've tried and where you are stuck. As Dima says, it's only an hour or two

Comment: This concept somewhat missing in scala collection. But I'm not sure... There must be other way around to achieve this. Honestly, i don't know yet how to implement this one (still trying), why I post the concept. Something like 1 to 10 by(Seq(2, 3, 4)).last  @TheArchetypalPaul thanks

Comment: @Dima sorry I did not get directly what you mean.

Comment: @mijzcx no problem, I'll explain again. If you need someone to write code for you, SO isn't the right resource to get that done. You'll probably have better luck at freelancer.com. If you are willing to make an effort and try doing it yourself, and the need advice with a concrete problem, that would be something SO community can help you with.

Comment: @mijzcx, Scala doesn't support what you want as standard. So you're not going to be able to just put a different argument in for `by` and somehow magically get the answer you want. You are going to have to implement a version of `by` that has the semantics you need. In fact, if you look at the source https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Range.scala you will see you can't use Range, as that's defined as something with a start, a stop and a single step value.  So, implement an iterator on say, List, to start with that takes one of your step values...

Comment: ... and returns the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Stream
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.util.Random

abstract class RangeX(override val head: Int, val end: Int, var step: Int) extends Stream[Int] {
  override val tailDefined = false
  override val isEmpty = head > end

  def by(steps: Seq[Int]) = {
    StepVariant(this, steps)
  }

  def byGroup(steps: Seq[Int]) = {
    StepVariantInGroup(this, steps)
  }

  def steps(steps: Seq[Int])(fn_steps: (Seq[Int], Int) => Int) = {
    var acc = new ListBuffer[Int]()
    this.zipWithIndex.foreach {
      case (i, idx) =>
        acc += i
        this.step = fn_steps(steps, idx)
    }
    acc.toList
  }

  def stepsByGroup(steps: Seq[Int])(fn_steps: (Seq[Int], Int) => Int) = {

    val ls = this.steps(steps)(fn_steps)
    var acc = new ListBuffer[List[Int]]()
    val lidx = ls.length - 1
    (1 to lidx).foreach { i =>
      acc += (ls(i - 1) to ls(i) - 1).toList
    }

    acc.toList
  }

  case class StepVariant(streams: RangeX, steps: Seq[Int]) {
    def repeating_steps = streams.steps(steps)(RangeX.repeating_steps)
    def repeat_last_step = streams.steps(steps)(RangeX.repeat_last_step)
    def random_steps = streams.steps(steps)(RangeX.random_steps)
    def reversing_steps = streams.steps(steps)(RangeX.reversing_steps)

  } 

  case class StepVariantInGroup(streams: RangeX, steps: Seq[Int]) {
    def repeating_steps = streams.stepsByGroup(steps)(RangeX.repeating_steps)
    def repeat_last_step = streams.stepsByGroup(steps)(RangeX.repeat_last_step)
    def random_steps = streams.stepsByGroup(steps)(RangeX.random_steps)
    def reversing_steps = streams.stepsByGroup(steps)(RangeX.reversing_steps)
  }

} 


class RangeSlaveX(_head: Int, _end: Int, _step: Int, val master: RangeX) extends RangeX(_head, _end, _step) {
  override def tail = if (isEmpty) Stream.Empty else new RangeSlaveX(head + master.step, end, master.step, master)
}

class RangeMasterX(_head: Int, _end: Int, _step: Int) extends RangeX(_head, _end, _step) {
  override def tail = if( isEmpty ) Stream.Empty else new RangeSlaveX(head + step, end, step, this)
}

object RangeX {
  implicit def toRangeX(range: Range): RangeX = new RangeMasterX(range.start, range.end, range.step)
  def apply(head: Int, end: Int, step: Int) = new RangeMasterX(head, end, step)

  def repeating_steps(steps: Seq[Int], idx: Int): Int = {
    val size = steps.size
    steps( idx % size )
  }

  def repeat_last_step(steps: Seq[Int], idx: Int): Int = {
    val len = steps.length - 1
    steps(if( idx >= len) len else idx)
  }

  def random_steps(steps: Seq[Int], idx: Int): Int = {
    Random.shuffle(steps).head
  }

  def reversing_steps(steps: Seq[Int], idx: Int): Int = {
    val size = steps.size
    val lidx = size - 1
    val forward = ((idx / size) % 2) == 0

    if(forward) {
      steps( idx % size )
    } else {
      steps( lidx - (idx % size))
    }
  }

}


scala> import RangeX._
import RangeX._
```

Method Chaining Way: - by and byGroup

```
scala> 1 to 20 byGroup Seq(1, 2, 3) reversing_steps  
res0: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9), List(10, 11), List(12), List(13), List(14, 15), List(16, 17, 18))

scala> 1 to 20 byGroup Seq(1, 2, 3) random_steps  
res1: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2, 3), List(4, 5), List(6, 7, 8), List(9, 10), List(11, 12), List(13, 14, 15), List(16, 17, 18))

scala> 1 to 20 byGroup Seq(1, 2, 3) repeating_steps  
res2: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7), List(8, 9), List(10, 11, 12), List(13), List(14, 15), List(16, 17, 18), List(19))

scala> 1 to 20 byGroup Seq(1, 2, 3) repeat_last_step    
res3: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9), List(10, 11, 12), List(13, 14, 15), List(16, 17, 18))

scala> 1 to 20 by Seq(1, 2, 3) reversing_steps  
res4: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 19)

scala> 1 to 20 by Seq(1, 2, 3) random_steps  
res5: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20)

scala> 1 to 20 by Seq(1, 2, 3) repeating_steps  
res6: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14, 16, 19, 20)

scala> 1 to 20 by Seq(1, 2, 3) repeat_last_step  
res7: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19)
```

Functional Way: - steps and stepsByGroup

```
scala> (1 to 20).steps(Seq(1, 2, 3))(reversing_steps)
res12: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 12, 13, 14, 16, 19)

scala> (1 to 20).steps(Seq(1, 2, 3))(random_steps)
res13: List[Int] = List(1, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 20)

scala> (1 to 20).steps(Seq(1, 2, 3))(repeating_steps)
res11: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14, 16, 19, 20)

scala> (1 to 20).steps(Seq(1, 2, 3))(repeat_last_step)
res15: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19)


scala> (1 to 20).stepsByGroup(Seq(1, 2, 3))(reversing_steps)
res17: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9), List(10, 11), List(12), List(13), List(14, 15), List(16, 17, 18))

scala> (1 to 20).stepsByGroup(Seq(1, 2, 3))(random_steps)
res18: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1, 2), List(3, 4), List(5), List(6), List(7), List(8, 9), List(10, 11), List(12, 13), List(14, 15, 16), List(17, 18, 19))

scala> (1 to 20).stepsByGroup(Seq(1, 2, 3))(repeating_steps)
res19: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7), List(8, 9), List(10, 11, 12), List(13), List(14, 15), List(16, 17, 18), List(19))

scala> (1 to 20).stepsByGroup(Seq(1, 2, 3))(repeat_last_step)
res20: List[List[Int]] = List(List(1), List(2, 3), List(4, 5, 6), List(7, 8, 9), List(10, 11, 12), List(13, 14, 15), List(16, 17, 18))
```

How's my revise implementation ^. Seed idea from @Piro implementation [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738623/incrementing-i-in-scala-for-loop-by-differing-amounts-depending-on-circumstanc). Thx.

**Step Variants**
*review* is repeating_steps
*last* is repeat_last_step
*random* is random_steps
*reverse* is reversing_steps

I wish Sir Martin Odersky add these kind of Range features `by(Seq(1,2,3)) *_steps` and `byGroup(Seq(1,2,3)) *_steps` in next Scala release :)